# Accessing MongoDB Data via Node Express for use with D3.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Node.js, and the whole MEAN stack, and have been trying to send my server side data to the browser, so I can use it and manipulate it with my client-side JavaScript (D3.JS). I've become somewhat familiar with the Node Express Framework and have set up a simple example to test this method using the following three files.

**db-connect.js**

```js
//Declare & Instantiate Connection Variables
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'my-connection-string'; //Hidden for obvious reasons, have tested
var busArray = []; //Declare Bus Array

//Create App Route & Connect To Database

exports.dbConnect = function dbConnect(req, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {

            //Create Cursor. Responsible For Iterating Over Collection Records
            var cursor = db.collection('busdata').find();

            //Invoke Each Method - Iterates Over Each Record & Executes It's Code Block
            cursor.each(function(err, item) {
                if (item != null) {
                    if (item.stopDate == '04-04-17') {

                        busObj = {}; //Declare Object Literal

                        busObj.bus_id = item.bus_id;
                        busObj.stopDate = item.stopDate;
                        busObj.stopTime = item.stopTime;
                        busObj.totalIn = item.totalIn;
                        busObj.totalOut = item.totalOut;
                        busObj.lat = item.lat;
                        busObj.lng = item.lng;

                        busArray.push(busObj);


                    }
                }

            }); //End of cursor
            //Callback
            jsonString = JSON.stringify(busArray); //Stringify The Array
            callback(null, busArray);
        } //end of else
    }); //end of mongoclient connect
}
```

**index.js** - the route file

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var database = require('../public/javascripts/db-connect.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    database.dbConnect(req, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {testString: JSON.stringify({'bus_id':3997}), busdata: data});
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.pug** - Page that I'm sending to

```js
doctype html
html
head
  title= 'Index Test Page'
  link(rel='icon', href='images/favicon.ico')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
body
  block content
      h1= 'Test Graph'
script(type='text/javascript').
  //var testString = !{testString}
  //console.log(testString)

  var myData = !{busdata}
  console.log(myData)
```

The final line `console.log(myData)` gives me `undefined` in my Google Chrome Console output. I figured this could be due to the asynchronous nature of the language so I tried creating a variable within **db-connect.js** and assigned it to a JSON Object called 'testJSON' with 6 objects.

I then passed it into my callback `callback(null, testJSON)`, updated the stringify line and restarted the server. I was able to successfully log the properties of the JSON Object.

I've tried using `setTimeout()` merely as a test but to no avail. What is the *proper* way of waiting for the data to come back from the MongoDB?

Comment: Yup! it's an async thing. Look at [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) in the MongoDB driver docs. It's for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.

Comment: To make that clear you would be replacing your `.each()` which is an async iterator with `.toArray()` which still requires a callback, but gives you the "whole array of results" inside the callback. If you are starting out, then start simple before you move on to larger result sets.

Comment: Yeah I have replaced my `.each()` with `.toArray()`. I'm now reading through the solutions to the other post in order to fix my async issue.